# How to use Transaction in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

How to use transactions in Entity Framework? I read some links on Stackoverflow : [Using Transactions or SaveChanges(false) and AcceptAllChanges()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/entity-framework-using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges)

BUT; i have 3 table so i have 3 entities:

```
CREATE TABLE Personel 
(PersonelID integer PRIMARY KEY identity not null, 
Ad varchar(30), 
Soyad varchar(30),
Meslek varchar(100),
DogumTarihi datetime,
DogumYeri nvarchar(100),
PirimToplamı float);

Go

create TABLE Prim
(PrimID integer PRIMARY KEY identity not null,
PersonelID integer Foreign KEY references Personel(PersonelID),
SatisTutari int,
Prim float,
SatisTarihi Datetime);

Go

CREATE TABLE Finans 
(ID integer PRIMARY KEY identity not null, 
Tutar float);
```

Personel, Prim, Finans my tables. If you look Prim table you can see Prim value float value if I write a textbox not float value my transaction must run.

```
using (TestEntities testCtx = new TestEntities())
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
       // do something...
       testCtx.Personel.SaveChanges();
       // do something...
       testCtx.Prim.SaveChanges();
       // do something...
       testCtx.Finans.SaveChanges();
       scope.Complete();
       success = true;
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: they use 3 different context.... you are trying to save each table independently?

Comment: You already have the code, what do you need help with ?

Comment: yes i want to add 3 table but transaction i must

Comment: you already use transaction with your transaction scope

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you make the call to [`SaveChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges), the Entity Framework will perform those operations in a single transaction.

When you use the [`TransactionScope` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope), you are saying "I want what runs in this block to be encapsulated in a larger transaction", which is indeed what you do.

When you call [`Complete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete) on the `TransactionScope`, that is what perform the committing of all of the operations encapsulated in the transaction defined by the `TransactionScope`.

Answer (score 1):

> SaveChanges operates within a transaction. SaveChanges will roll back that transaction and throw an exception if any of the dirty ObjectStateEntry objects cannot be persisted.

from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar [example in the MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx).