# Entity Framework - SQL Server - Transactions handling

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, transactions

I am using ASP.Net Web Forms, .Net Framework 3.5, Entity Framework
In my application I am doing inserts using entity model and then calling `SaveChanges()`, I know in this case Entity model handles the transactions and if any query fails, everything will be reverted.

But in few cases, I use a SQL-Server SP to insert data in different tables. This SP has 4 to 5 insert queries. I want to know that if any one query in SP fails, will Entity model revert the other queries or not? I don't think entity model will handle that - right?
Is there any workaround or I'll have to use Entity model to insert data for handling transactions?

Comment: Try changing your sp to fail on purpose halfway through and see if any changes persist.

Comment: If you have SP, you can handle the transaction in SP itself. I guess this is the better way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) class. This will ensure an Atomic transaction

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{

     mySP.Insert();

     context.SaveChanges();

     scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: So if any insert/update or delete query in my SP fails, executed queries will be reverted too? Do I need to write something specific in my SP?

Comment: @eFriend your SP should throw an exception if it fails. if any one of the operations fail all will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

[Entity Framework - Using Transactions or SaveChanges(false) and AcceptAllChanges()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/entity-framework-using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges)

Comment: I have gone through that question already, but it doesn't answer my question.