# Undo Redo with Entity Framework

Tags: .net, frameworks, entity, undo, redo

I'm converting a .net program's db access from old school sql to EntityFramework
currently it has an 'undo redo' feature by holding the sql scripts in a container for later use.

Is there an easy way to implement undo redo mechanism with entity framework?

Thank you very much
Rony

--EDIT--
I think I didn't explain myself properly.. I need to keep all history to my SQL SELECT queries. In the previous app I kept such list of all my queries and this allowed me to perform any number of undo / redo steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement such behavior taking advantage of DbContext's Property Values. This ADO.NET team blog article explains it in good detail: [Using DbContext in EF 4.1 Part 5: Working with Property Values](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/30/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-5-working-with-property-values.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use `SaveChanges(false)`  and `AcceptAllChanges()` function.

Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/entity-framework-using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges) out here is the explanation of your problem.

Hope this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score -1):

[This new O/R-Mapping-Framework](http://www.ffentityframework.net) with included Model-View-Controller-Framework supports Undo-Management.