# Transactional operation with SaveChanges and ExecuteStoreCommand

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a problem that I would like to share. The context is a bit messy, so I will try to do my best in the explanation.

I need to create a transactional operation over a number of entities. I'm working with EF CodeFirst but with a legacy database that I can't change. In order to create a more consistent model than the database provides I'm projecting the database information into a more refined entities I created on my own.

As I need to use different contexts, my initial idea was to use TransactionScope which gave me good results in the past. Why do I need different contexts? Due to diverse problems with db, I can't make the updates only in one operation (UnitOfWork). I need to retrieve different IDs which only appears after SaveChanges().

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    Operation1();
    Operation2();
    Operation3(uses ExecuteStoreCommand)
    SaveChanges();

    Operation4();
    SaveChanges();
}
```

I know that, in order to use TransactionScope, I need to share the same connection among all the operations (And I'm doing it, passing the context to the objects). However, when I execute one of the operations (which uses ExecuteStoreCommand) or I try to do some update after the first SaveChanges I always receive the **MSDTC error** (the support for distributed transactions is disabled) or even more rare, as **unloaded domains**.

I don't know if someone can help me, at least to know which is the best direction for this scenario.

Comment: Looks like the entityconnection opens new connections below the hood. Maybe you can hook on [StateChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.statechange.aspx) to get more detail.

Comment: If you are connecting to different databases (or you are using Sql Server 2005) your transaction is being promoted to a distributed transaction. Note that if you are using Sql Server 2005 the transaction is automatically promoted to a distributed transaction since EF will open connection more than once. If you want to share the same connection among multiple contexts you should open the connection inside a transaction (this should automatically enlist the connection in the transaction) and pass the connection to the context ctor. EF will not close connection it did not open.

Comment: Note that opening connection on your own is also a way to prevent from promoting the transaction to a distributed transaction on Sql Server 2005 since EF will not close and reopen the connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at this answer:
[Entity Framework - Using Transactions or SaveChanges(false) and AcceptAllChanges()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/entity-framework-using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges)
The answer does exactly what you require having a transaction, over multiple data contexts.

This post on [Transactions and Connections in Entity Framework 4.0](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2010/06/29/Transactions-and-Connections-in-Entity-Framework-40.aspx) I found really helpful too.

For people who may need a simpler solution, here's what I use when I need to mix ExecuteStoreCommand and SaveChanges in a transaction.

```
using (var dataContext = new ContextEntities())
{
   dataContext.Connection.Open();
   var trx = dataContext.Connection.BeginTransaction();

   var sql = "DELETE TestTable WHERE SomeCondition";
   dataContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(sql);

   var list = CreateMyListOfObjects(); // this could throw an exception
   foreach (var obj in list)
      dataContext.TestTable.AddObject(obj);
   dataContext.SaveChanges(); // this could throw an exception

   trx.Commit();
}
```

Comment: The connection is automagically closed when the context falls out of scope, i.e. at the end of the using statement.