# Entity Framework - Transactions replacing SaveChanges(bool) with SaveChanges(SaveOptions)

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

This is a follow up question to [Using Transactions or SaveChanges(false) and AcceptAllChanges()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/815586/37759)

Specifically about this line `context2.SaveChanges(false);`

Now SaveChanges(bool) is deprecated. We are supposed to use SaveChanges(SaveOptions) instead.

The [SaveOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.saveoptions.aspx) has following options:

- None
- AcceptAllChangesAfterSave
- DetectChangesBeforeSave

Which of these map to SaveChanges(false)?

Answer (score 11):

`SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave)` is equivalent of `SaveChanges(false)`