# Save multiple objects from different classes in one commit

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

I would like to know what's the best way to save multiple objects in a way that if the second 'obj.Insert()' throw a exception, all the changes rollback.

I a'm trying something like that:

```
Product product1 = new Product();
Product product2 = new Product();
Product product3 = new Product();

DbContext DB = new DB();

IProductInsert repository = new ProductInsert(DB);

repository.Insert(product1);
repository.Insert(product2);
repository.Insert(product3);

DB.SaveChanges();
```

But it is in my view, I think it's not correct..

How can I save all the changes or rollback using the DB.SaveChanges() in my repository classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it with a transaction scope:

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope()) {
    repository.Insert(product1);
    repository.Insert(product2);
    repository.Insert(product3);
    DB.SaveChanges();
    ts.Complete();
}
```

If anything fails in this sequence, and the call `ts.Complete()` is not reached, the background transaction is rolled back.

For a solution that works across multiple db contexts, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/815660/335858).

Comment: Niceeee.. but VS do not find System.Transaction.. why is it?

Comment: @murilokunze You need to add a reference to `System.Transactions` to the list of references of your project (right-click "References", choose "Add Reference...", open ".NET" tab, and add `System.Transactions` from there).

Comment: Now it works :).. but I have one more doubt.. should I use transactionScope in my view?

Comment: @murilokunze No - setting up transaction scope and performing database operations belong in the controller code, not in the view code.