# SaveChanges vs. AcceptAllChanges in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What's the difference between, `_context.SaveChanges` and `_context.AcceptAllChanges()`, is the `AcceptAllChanges()` is sort of reloading data from Database or rolling back (discarding) changes made by the user when he didn't use `SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[ObjectContext.AcceptAllChanges Method  - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.acceptallchanges.aspx)

> If the [SaveChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savechanges.aspx) method was called and the [AcceptAllChangesAfterSave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.saveoptions.aspx)
>   was not specified, the user must call the AcceptAllChanges method. The
>   AcceptAllChanges method is useful in the scenario where a transaction
>   has failed and a user wants to retry.

You may see this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/01/11/savechanges-false.aspx

> If you call SaveChanges() or SaveChanges(true),the EF simply assumes
>   that if its work completes okay, everything is okay, so it will
>   discard the changes it has been tracking, and wait for new changes.
>
> Unfortunately though if something goes wrong somewhere else in the
>   transaction, because the EF discarded the changes it was tracking, we
>   can’t recover.
>
> This is where SaveChanges(false) and AcceptAllChanges() come in.
>
> SaveChanges(false) tells the EF to execute the necessary database
>   commands, but hold on to the changes, so they can be replayed if
>   necessary.
>
> Now if the broader transaction fails you can retry the EF specific
>   bits, with another call to SaveChanges(false). Alternatively you can
>   walk through the state-manager to log what failed.
>
> Once the broader transaction succeeds, you simply call
>   AcceptAllChanges() manually, and the changes that were being tracked
>   are discarded.

Answer (score 3):

From the Accessing Data with Microsoft .Net Framework 4 book:

> When working with the Entity Framework, the submission of changes to
>   the database is automatically handled within a transaction when you
>   call the SaveChanges method on the ObjectContext object. Also, the
>   AcceptAllChanges method is automatically called if no exception is
>   thrown when updating, which will reset the state of all objects to
>   Unchanged. Although the SaveChanges method is executed within a
>   transaction, you might need to create your own transaction if you need
>   to perform other operations within the same transaction