# Simple connection between SQL Server CE, Entity Framework, and WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I've created a simple Form containing two TextBoxes for name and age, and a button to submit. I added a "Local Database" to my project called `Sample.sdf`.

I've created a table called `Customers` and added three columns: `Id`, `Name`, and `Age`.
I've set the `Id` column as the primary key but didn't set it as an identity column.

Then, I added an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" called `SampleEntities`. I selected "Generate from database" and chose the `Sample.sdf`. I've selected the table and clicked Finish.

In my `Button_Click` event I've done:

```
using (SampleEntities se = new SampleEntities())
{
   Customer c = new Customer();
   c.Id = FindNextId();
   c.Age = Convert.ToDouble(txtAge.Text);
   c.Name = txtAge.Text;

   se.AddToCustomers(c);
   se.AcceptAllChanges();
   se.SaveChanges();
}
MessageBox.Show("Done");
```

I'm getting the "Done" message with no problems, but the records are not showing in the ***Server Explorer - Customers table - Show Table Data*** option.

Note: I know that in runtime, the sdf file is located in my debug folder. I'm checking both the sdf file in the project directory, and the sdf file in the debug folder, and neither have any records. Furthermore, I have set my sdf file property "Copy To Output Directory" to "Copy if newer".

So my question is, where is the customer row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your `AcceptAllChanges` call. You do not need to call it; just call `SaveChanges`.

```
using (SampleEntities se = new SampleEntities())
{
   Customer c = new Customer();
   c.Id = FindNextId();
   c.Age = Convert.ToDouble(txtAge.Text);
   c.Name = txtAge.Text;
   se.AddToCustomers(c);

   se.SaveChanges();
}
MessageBox.Show("Done");
```

You only need to call `AcceptAllChanges` if you call one of:

- `SaveChanges(false)`
- `SaveChanges(SaveOptions.None)`
- `SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave)`

When you call `SaveChanges()`, (with no arguments), "accepting all changes" happens automatically.

Comment: You are right ! so please tell me what is the difference between AcceptAllChanges and SaveChanges ? And when I use each ?

Comment: @subirshan Explained it a little in the answer. See Chris's answer, too, as well as [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859304/savechanges-vs-acceptallchanges-in-entity-framework?lq=1).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to call the `AcceptAllChanges` method (1), you must save changes **before** accepting them.

```
se.SaveChanges();
se.AcceptAllChanges();
```

The [`AcceptAllChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.acceptallchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) method iterates all the ObjectStateEntry objects within the ObjectStateManager that are *Added* or *Modified*, and then sets the state of the entry to *Unchanged*. The *Deleted* items become detached.

So when you call `SaveChanges` after `AcceptAllChanges`, there is nothing to save.

---

(1) As @Sahuagin pointed out, there is generally no need  to call the `AcceptAllChanges` method.  If you call `SaveChanges()` you don't need to call `AcceptAllChanges` at all.

You only must call the method when you use the `SaveChanges(SaveOptions)` method and do not specify the `AcceptAllChangesAfterSave` in `SaveOptions`.

Comment: From what I read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859304/savechanges-vs-acceptallchanges-in-entity-framework) I think that calling `AcceptAllChanges` is only necessary if you called `SaveChanges(false)`. If you call `SaveChanges()` or equivalently `SaveChanges(true)`, you don't need to call `AcceptAllChanges` at all.

Comment: @Sahuagin You are right. Note, however, that the `SaveChanges(Boolean)` method is obsolete