# How can I roll back insert or delete on database in Mvc core

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core

In MVC core 2.2 we can use `savechanges` method after database actions(`Insert/Delete/Edit`). Now my question is:

Is there any way to **roll back** my actions after calling `savechanges` or is there any method to do it?

please guide me!!

Comment: I think there is 2 options for you: 1. Do not call SaveChanges() before you sure that you've done all the things right in your code.
2. Handle changes manually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859304/savechanges-vs-acceptallchanges-in-entity-framework

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. What exactly is the issue/problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: please See This Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges

Comment: There's not enough information to answer this question without knowing what technology you're using for database access. I.e. Dapper, EF, ADO.NET, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do rollback with `SqlTransaction`.