# How use Transaction in EntityFramework 5?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I want to trancate some table same time.
If one not success, must be all rolback.

Something like that:

```
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table tb_expensesall");
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table tb_wholesale");
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table tb_singlesale");
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table tb_purchase");
```

But the problem is , I dont know how use transaction for this.

I trying this:

```
using (gasstationEntities ctx = new gasstationEntities(Resources.CONS))
{
    ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
    DbTransaction tr = ctx.Database.Connection.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table tb_expensesall");
        ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table tb_wholesale");
        ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table tb_singlesale");
        ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table tb_purchase");
        //commit the transaction
        tr.Commit();
        new MessageWindow(this, Resources.GetString("Warn"), Resources.GetString("DeleteSuccess"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //return
        tr.Rollback();
    }
    //close
    ctx.Database.Connection.Close();
}
```

The problem here:  `tr.Commit();`
and the Exception tell me :

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open to rollback transaction
```

And the `tr.Rollback();` throw exception to.
the exception is:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open to rollback transaction
```

The realy funy thing is , the table truncate is success. what? the commmit is throw exception . and it can be success? i can't understand.

Please tel me  what is goning on . if you give me a solution, that's even better.

Comment: have you tried using a transactionscope? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/entity-framework-using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges

Comment: I agreee just wrap the whole thing in a TransactionScope and it will just take care of it for you.

Comment: One issue here is that `TRUNCATE` operations are not logged (unlike `DELETE FROM <table>`) and, therefore, cannot be wrapped in a transaction.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add reference to `System.Transactions`, import `using System.Transactions;` and then try to encapsulate your code by

```
using (gasstationEntities ctx = new gasstationEntities(Resources.CONS))
{
   using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
   {
      [... your code...]

      scope.Complete();
   }
}
```

If exception occurs, scope.Complete() is not called and the rollback is automatic.

**EDIT :** I've just seen your MySql tag. If this doesn't work, have a look [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1239791.aspx/1) !

Comment: @qakmak : so with the good DLL reference and the "`using System.Transactions;`" at the top of your file, is it working ?

Comment: but the problem is , if have a exception in the ExecuteSqlCommand2 . the ExecuteSqlCommand1 is success. how let the command success together or not success together. for exsample: ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table tb_expensesall");
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table tb_wholesale");
throw new Exception("error");
scope.Complete();
     if there is have error , the two ExecuteSqlCommand succwss. why? the scope not execute method Complete.

Comment: So the Mysql transaction problem with TransactionScope is probably not fixed yet... As said in the link, you can try the old way. See [that exemple](http://forums.asp.net/p/1239791/2262323.aspx/1?Re+Does+TransactionScope+work+really+with+MySql+).

Comment: the old way can't rooback transaction to. and i find the problem . we can't use trancate table. we must use delete table. now i'm use TransactionScope and Entity Framework can be work. i just change the t-sql command truancate table XX to delte from XX.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,
Technically, the using should commit the transaction when there are no exceptions, but in case of exception, the using will automatically rollback it.

```
using (var txn = new TransactionScope())
{
    ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table tb_expensesall");
    ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table tb_wholesale");
    ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table tb_singlesale");
    ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table tb_purchase");
    txn.Complete();
}
new MessageWindow(this, Resources.GetString("Warn"), Resources.GetString("DeleteSuccess"));
```

Comment: Commit is missing :) And close the scope before showing a message.

Comment: but where is the TransactionScope ? ef5 the me not found the method or property.

Comment: it can't be use . if second throw error. the first is success. why?

Comment: @qakmak, add reference to System.Transactions.dll