# Doing transactions with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework-5, transactionscope

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/entity-framework-using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges)  to explain how to do transactions with Entity Framework
However the solution does not work with code first.
I have experimented and my tests indicate the following does work

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
        DBContext1.SaveChanges()
        If (ForceFailure) return 0  // used in testing
        DBContext2.SaveChanges()
        scope.Complete();
 }
```

However I feel nervous because I am no longer passing parameters to SaveChanges or calling AcceptAllChanges

How do I establish whether I can trust my solution?

Comment: What aspect (DB consistency, context consistency, etc.) do you not trust?

Comment: I want to know that either both savechanges run or neither runs. My tests indicate that this is the case. However because the code seems so different to the earlier EF version, I am looking for some peer or documented validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SaveChanges(Boolean)` is part of `ObjectContext`, not `DbContext`. Note that the method `SaveChanges(Boolean)` in `ObjectContext` is deprecated in favor of [`SaveChanges(SaveOptions)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395500.aspx).

If you still want to use `DbContext`, you may be able to overload its own `SaveChanges` method to use [IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696590.aspx), by using an extension method for example.

Comment: DbContext does have a SaveChanges method

Comment: It does, but it isn't the same method (`DbContext` doesn't extend `ObjectContext`), which is why it lacks the arguments you need. You can, however, retrieve a reference to the `ObjectContext` used internally by the `DbContext` via the `IObjectContextAdapter` interface that `DbContext` implements, and use the `SaveChanges` method you need.

Comment: Can you tell me where you found that the DBContext SaveChanges is deprecated?  I have found references that it is the other way around - but not from Microsoft.

Comment: I'm talking about `SaveChanges(Boolean)` from `ObjectContext`, not the one from `DbContext`. Let me clarify:
There are two methods, `ObjectContext.SaveChanges` and `DbContext.SaveChanges`. `ObjectContext.SaveChanges` is overloaded, and one of its variants (the one which accepts a boolean) is deprecated in favor of another (the one which accepts `SaveOptions`). This has nothing to do with `DbContext.SaveChanges`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Are you able to tell me whether objectContext.SaveChanges with SaveOptions is better than DBContext.SaveChanges  and if so why?

Comment: `ObjectContext` and `DbContext` are really two different APIs, although with a similar goal. From what I gather, `DbContext` was created after `ObjectContext` to provide a simpler API mainly for code-first scenarios (removing the need for some boilerplate that `ObjectContext` requires) -- in fact, as I already hinted at, `DbContext` actually uses an `ObjectContext` internally, so it's effectively a wrapper. There may be other reasons, see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=objectcontext+vs+dbcontext. In theory you shouldn't need `ObjectContext.SaveChanges`, but you may have hit a limitation.

Comment: This has been deprecated in more recent versions of the framework. `SaveChanges(Boolean)` has been replaced by `SaveChanges(SaveOptions)`, which still needs to be referenced from `IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext` in code first.