# Linq Db.SaveChanges use with ForEach Loop

Tags: c#, sql

I have a Sql table with 12000 records and need to copy it to another table.

```
mset1 md = new mset1();
mset2 pd = new mset2();
foreach (var b in md.Myset) //dbset
{
    Obj m = new Obj()
    {
        coslat = b.coslat,//float
        Code = b.Code.Remove(b.Code.Length - 1),//string
        sinlat = b.sinlat,//float
        lat = b.lat,//float
        lon = b.lon,//float
        latrad = b.latrad,//float
        lonrad = b.lonrad //float
    };
    pd.Postcodeset.Add(m);
    pd.SaveChanges();
}
```

What I want to know when should I `SaveChanges()` efficiently. Should it be inside the `For` Loop or should it go outside the `For` Loop.

Edit: I am worried because I have `7 floats` and the `string Code` is on average 10kb each. If I dont save changes inside the `For` Loop I might run out of memory.

Comment: What is your definition of efficient? Speed? Low memory consumption? It all depends.

However, I would think that outside the loop is better, but that's having not tested it

Comment: @DanDrews I have 6 floating points and dont want to run out of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be best to place it outside the loop - this would mean that once the processing has completed, the data layer will be updated.

Something else to mention / a suggestion:
Place the `foreach` code within a `Try Catch` and use the `RollBack()` in the case of an exception. This will "rollback" any change(s) made to the database and avoid having a negative impact - de.

[RollBack Function](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8281e05-8136-4cb8-ad52-63e6dd14718c/linq-rollback)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Place it outside the for loop.

You are adding to the collection (`PostCodeSet`) in your foreach, but only need to commit the collection once, therefore it makes sense to call `SaveChanges` once rather than `n` times.

Answer (score 0):

You should move

```
pd.SaveChanges();
```

outside of the loop so you only make 1 call to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would always put it outside the for loop.  Not for performance reasons but because the changes will be done within a transaction.

I would expect it to be more efficient as well because your making less requests to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of doing just one `SaveChanges` once you have added multiple rows is that all of the updates will be done under a [unit of work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/entity-framework-using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges).

If high performance for bulk inserts is your primarly requirement, then I believe you have the wrong tool for the job - e.g. look at [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move this outside the `loop`.

It save all the change after adding data in `pd.Postcodeset`.