# Entity Framework Transaction handling

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
MyEntities myNewObject = new MyEntities();
MyEntities2 myNewObject2 = new MyEntities2();

using (var context = new MyContext())
{
  context.MyEntities.AddObject(myNewObject);
  context.SaveChanges(); //saves myNewObject

  myNewObject2.MyEntitiesID =  myNewObject.Id;
  context.MyEntities2.AddObject(myNewObject2);
  context.SaveChanges(); //saves myNewObject2 with ID of myNewObject
}
```

Now I would like to handle this as a transaction. If the insert of myNewObject2 fails, myNewObject is already in the database. There is no reference between these objects in the database.

Comment: Please review this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/entity-framework-using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges) and its answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SaveChanges will save both your changes in a transaction if you omit the first SaveChanges().

Antoher option is use a transactionscope

```
using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
  //...do operations
  trans.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that SaveChanges() will save with a transaction? I was not aware of that!

Comment: Yes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843.aspx - "In all versions of Entity Framework, whenever you execute SaveChanges() to insert, update or delete on the database the framework will wrap that operation in a transaction.")

Comment: Is there nothing on myContext to perform what @fubo wants? Using TransactionScope looks odd to me.

Comment: You can create your own transaction with context.Database.BeginTransaction()