# Importing data with EF. How context.saveChanges() could save the valid ones, despite there are invalids (throwing Exception)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

Sometimes I am importing 5000+ rows (of different entity types) into my DB. I use Entity Framework and I want the context to save the rows that fits on my model, if there are invalid ones they should be discarded.

**I am inside a transaction, so :**
I need to decide at the end of the iteration if i want to Complete() the transacion or Dispose() ,It depends on which kind of entity throws the exception.

I think there are 2 possibilities:

1. **Check if a entity object is valid** before context.Add(object)
2. **Add the 5000** items and, set in some way that **context.SaveChanges()** , saves the valid one and discard the invalid ones (now it throws an exception and discard all added items).

I am asking for a snippet of code, or some indications i can follow to solve that situation. I want only to import the valid items and generate a log of the invalid ones.

Thanks. I will mark as an answer if you solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 is the more sensible approach.  Adding 5000 objects and then saving changes is very non-performant.  A better approach is

```
 while (null != (entity = GetNextEntity())
 {
    if (entity.IsValid())
    {
        context.Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
```

**Update -- Ignore SQL errors**

```
 while (null != (entity = GetNextEntity())
 {
    try
    {
        context.Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception) { /* eat it */ }
 }
```

Comment: I dont have isValid()  method in my entity

Comment: So no validation logic.  Do you want to just ignore SQL errors?

Comment: Thats not working cause the context could have the invalid entity added so every time i try to add new items(if there are invalid ones) you will get an exception as you don´t dispose the context.I am inside transaction so i can´t dispose my context.

Comment: Sorry you've changed the whole meaning of the question by saying you are inside a transaction.  Good luck mate.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/entity-framework-using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges