# Can we define a distributed transaction with Database.BeginTransaction?

Tags: c#, transactions, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6, distributed-transactions

I've searched about ways of creating a transaction in Entity Framework and I know that we can create a distributed transaction with TransactionScope in EF5 as stated here.
[Using Transactions or SaveChanges(false) and AcceptAllChanges()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/entity-framework-using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges)
I wanna know if we can create a distributed transaction with Database.BeginTransaction?
thanks in advance.

Comment: The link doesn't necessarily involve distributed transactions. DTs are across network hosts. Is that what you refer to? AFAIK a `DbTransaction` (which is started by Database.BeginTransaction) can never escalate to DTC.

Answer (score 0):

Database.BeginTransaction will allways start a local transaction in the database, not a distributed transaction.

Creating a new TransactionScope will start with a local database transaction, but that will automatically upgrade to a distributed transaction when needed.  That is: if you're working with a SQL Server database.  When using other databases, creating a TransactionScope will create a distributed transaction.
That is because only SQL Server supports transaction promotion...