# UnitOfWork pattern for Entity Framework but with direct SQL queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns, unit-of-work

I'm trying to incorporate the Unit of Work pattern for my ASP.NET MVC project, and it is a bit different than other typical UoW design with Entity Framework.

My database has a highly normalised and pure relational structure in that it is not really **EF friendly**. Because of this I have created views that are mapped to entities so that I can still have all the EF and LINQ goodness when querying, but I have to use **direct sql queries** (e.g. `Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`) when updating the entities.

This poses a challenge to my UoW design. As far as I know a general approach to UoW with EF is to basically call `Context.SaveChanges()` only when `UoW.Commit()` is called. This way all the tracked entity changes will be committed as a single transaction to the database at once.

However since I am using `Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`, whenever I update an entity the transaction will happen **immediately**, hence losing the whole point of UoW. I'll give an example:

Traditional UoW with EF:

```
public void CreateOrder()
{
    var customer = new Customer();
    // this only adds the entity to the Context for tracking
    // e.g. Context.Customers.Add(customer);
    UoW.CustomerRepo.Add(customer); 

    // this too only adds the entity to the Context
    var order = new Order();
    UoW.OrderRepo.Add(order);

    // Commit. this internally calls Context.SaveChanges()
    // sending all changes to the db in a single transaction
    // Perhaps also with a TransactionScope.
    UoW.Commit(); 
}
```

My UoW with EF:

```
public void CreateOrder()
{
    var customer = new Customer();
    // this inserts a customer to the db immediately
    // e.g. Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(insertSql);
    UoW.CustomerRepo.Add(customer); 

    // This too inserts an order immediately
    var order = new Order();
    UoW.OrderRepo.Add(order);

    // There is no point calling Context.SaveChanges()
    // here as all my changes are already executed with direct sql.
    UoW.Commit(); 
}
```

Anyone has come across similar issues? Should I just abandon UoW here and simply wrap all my repository actions in a single `TransactionScope`?

Comment: Take a look on this SO (the answer with 61 votes): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/entity-framework-using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges

Comment: You can combine both EF and ExecuteSqlCommand as long as you begin a transaction before issuing the commands. And, if I am not mistaken, when EF is asked to save changes it will use an existing transaction if available.

Comment: Thanks mate that post was very helpful. I ended up ditching UoW and go with transaction scope only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UoW will not work with straight SQL as ADO.net queries/commands are not lazy. You need ADO.net transactions to wrap all  your SQL queries. UoW is essentially a transactional pattern that wraps over your repositories to produce transaction like behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer, I knew I could still get help from SO even during Christmas :)