# Use ExecuteCommand in Linq to Sql with Transaction

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to update tables using `ExecuteCommand()` in below manner:

```
using (var context = new FMDataContext())
{
    // how do I execute below two steps in a single transaction?
    context.ExecuteCommand("Update Table1 set X = 1 Where Y = 2");
    context.ExecuteCommand("Update Table2 set X = 3 Where Y = 4");
}
```

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges) for this but it's for EF, I am using [Linq To Sql](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/different-between-linq-to-sql-and-entity-framework).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Transactions or SaveChanges(false) and AcceptAllChanges()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges) [Second answer]

Comment: you span a transaction scope around your calls and around your using statement

Comment: @SᴇM That answer is for EF. I am using Linq-To-Sql. See https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/different-between-linq-to-sql-and-entity-framework.

Comment: @AbbasFaisal you are not using Linq2Sql you are using rawsql. You are using the DataBase-Context at most.

Comment: @MongZhu My context class inherits from DataContext in System.Data.Linq namespace. It says "Represents the main entry point for the LINQ to SQL framework." above the definition. May be I should say I am executing rawsql using Linq2Sql DataContext.

Comment: That would be a better description. If you would use linq2sql you wouldn't need any strings. You would use the given query syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to span a [TransactionScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Transactions.TransactionScope);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) around your calls:

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{

    using (var context = new FMDataContext())
    {            
        context.ExecuteCommand("Update Table1 set X = 1 Where Y = 2");
        context.ExecuteCommand("Update Table2 set X = 3 Where Y = 4");
    }
    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Was looking for something in Linq To Sql. But let me try this.