# ASP.NET Razor - How to create a POST form for List of objects?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I need to create a POST form to add new objects to database. I have to create a Razor page where I can add new lesson form on click of a button. And after it on click of another button all the lessons should be added to DB context. I still don't know how to do it so I want you to help me

```
 public class Course
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public List<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; } = new List<Lesson>();
}
public class Lesson
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Here is some image of what I mean: [image]

DB has a Course table and a Lesson table. Please tell me how I can create a page to create new 'Course' with dynamic amount of 'Lessons'

Comment: `lessons` can be multiple it is?

Comment: yes, it can be multiple

Comment: For this, you need to create one method with the `List<Lession> parameter and post the data using cshtml. or you can Directly pass the course model into parameters.

Comment: You can refer to the official doc about [Adding a related entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data#adding-a-related-entity).

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this in your controller method you need to pass from the page.

```
public ActionResult PostMethod(Course course, FormCollection formCollection)
{
    string title = course.Title; // Title value
    string category = course.Category; // Category value
    //add course into database
    if (course.Lessons != null && course.Lessons.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in course.Lessons)
        {
            //add Lessons into database
        }
    }
}
```

Please note in this example you are going to perform many operations in `databases`
you have to manage `transaction` as well for this.

[Using Transactions or SaveChanges(false) and AcceptAllChanges()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges)